# Is mongodb able to index a null value?

Tags: mongodb

I have an post whose field `postStatus` I want to set as either true false, or null. I was wondering whether mongo would be able to index null values.

Also, is there any difference if I choose to do null, true and false vs using -1,0,1 (or any 3 ints)?

thanks

Comment: Take look for sparse indexes https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/core/index-sparse/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Indexing of null

Yes, `null` values are indexed, as can be proven if you try to add a second `null` value to a unique index:

```
connecting to: test
> db.idxtest.createIndex({a:1},{unique:true})
{
    "createdCollectionAutomatically" : true,
    "numIndexesBefore" : 1,
    "numIndexesAfter" : 2,
    "ok" : 1
}
> db.idxtest.insert({a:"foo"})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.idxtest.insert({b:"bar"})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.idxtest.insert({c:"baz"})
WriteResult({
    "nInserted" : 0,
    "writeError" : {
        "code" : 11000,
        "errmsg" : "E11000 duplicate key error index: test.idxtest.$a_1 dup key: { : null }"
    }
})
```

Another way to demonstrate that null values matter is by sorting on an indexed field for which documents contain `null` values:

```
> db.idxtest2.createIndex({a:1})
{
    "createdCollectionAutomatically" : true,
    "numIndexesBefore" : 1,
    "numIndexesAfter" : 2,
    "ok" : 1
}
> db.idxtest2.insert({a:1})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.idxtest.insert({a:2})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.idxtest2.insert({b:2})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.idxtest2.insert({a:null})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.idxtest2.find().sort({a:1})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56786a93ada44c7ffcd38f9f"), "b" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56786aa1ada44c7ffcd38fa0"), "a" : null }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56786a65ada44c7ffcd38f9d"), "a" : 1 }
> db.idxtest2.find().sort({a:-1})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56786a65ada44c7ffcd38f9d"), "a" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56786aa1ada44c7ffcd38fa0"), "a" : null }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56786a93ada44c7ffcd38f9f"), "b" : 2 }
```

Note that implicit `null` values have precedence; so to say, they are "more" `null` since they do not even have the according key.

## On Booleans

As per [BSON specification](http://bsonspec.org/spec.html), a boolean value is a single byte, whereas an integer is at least a 32-bit integer consuming 4 bytes. So it does make a difference and if you have millions of entries that would amount to... ...well, a few megabytes. ;) So for all *practical* purposes there is no difference.

Comment: would I be able to index on a if I set, ,{unique:false} (i may have multiple values set to null)

Comment: Have a look at the second example.

Comment: Are you sure non-unique indexes store null values though?

Comment: @Andy Sparse indexes don't.

Comment: I'm perplexed that this is marked as correct and nobody thought to mention that the proof is simply to do `db.idxtest2.explain('executionStats').find({a: null})` which shows clearly the index being utilized

Comment: @Ryba The answer is almost 8 years old...